# Show data in StatusBar in Delphi xe7 using Multi-device-Application

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

before this Component (statusBar) was used  in previous Delphi version like the following : StatusBar1.Panel[0].Text := 'data' ;
And in Delphi xe7 this component behaviour  has been changed to I don't know  ,
Could you please let me know how to insert data in StatusBar using Delphi XE7 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`TStatusBar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FMX.StdCtrls.TStatusBar) in FMX acts like a container. So you must drop controls onto it in order to draw some text. on this case you must drop a [`TLabel`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FMX.StdCtrls.TLabel) and then modify the [`Text`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FMX.Controls.TTextControl.Text) property.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification , could you please send me an example  ?

Comment: Delphi include a large collection of FMX project samples, try this one [FMX.ControlsDemo Sample](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE7/en/FMX.ControlsDemo_Sample)